# Pullback of torsion-free sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between integral scheme. Let $F$ be a torsion-free sheaf on $Y$.

> Is $f^*F$ torsion-free? How about when $\dim X=\dim Y=1$?

Comment: This is not true even for dimension one. Take $Y$ to be the spectrum of $k[t^2,t^3]$ and $X$ to be spectrum of $k[t]$ with the obvious morphism. Take the torsion free sheaf given by the maximal ideal $(t^2,t^3)$.

Comment: I didn't see it, please elaborate the example

Comment: Did you calculate the pull back carefully?

Comment: Is it the sheaf associated to the module $k[t]\otimes (t^2,t^3)$?

Comment: Yes. Can you show that this module has torsion?

Comment: I didn't see the torsion elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140406/discussion-between-z-a-z-z-and-mohan).